# Should you specify Node.js built-in modules as “dependencies?”

Tags: node.js

Node.js has [several built-in modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_builtinmodules) that can be used without any further installation. When I write a package that *requires* these, I wonder if I should add them to the “dependencies” field of the `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to add them to your dependencies, and you should not add them to your dependencies. NPM uses this list to fetch modules from the repository, but built-ins don't need to be fetched since they are already provided by Node. As noted below there can be conflicts with package names in the repository.

Comment: Do I _not need_ to do that, or do I _have to_ not do that? Does something undesired happen if I do that (for a documentation purpose)?

Comment: You _should not_ do that. The internal modules are loaded from the NodeJS runtime directly. To make things worse, the external npm registry will almost certainly have a module with same name as one of the internal modules. If you explicitly add a dependency on these modules you will end-up bundling wrong and possibly outdated/malicious code with you app. Do note `require('internal-module-name')` would still return the 'right' internal module, but you will still have the 'wrong' code sitting in your prod box nevertheless.